# Swift 5 - Creating a heavily reference based app. - Data Structure

Tags: swift, core-data, data-structures, icloud

I'm working on creating an app that is heavily data based. - I have hundreds of materials that make up the backbone of the app. And I'm not sure how I should structure the data. - I've used realm in the past, but I'm wanting to use Core Data so I can use iCloud.

Currently I have these materials as a struct. The struct has about 30 constants. Mostly basic
variables, but also some arrays and enums.

I also currently have a file for each material, and the material is set as a global constant.

I've then made a second struct to combine all the materials with additional variables. And then a global variable thats used to referenced the data.

Struct (Of type Material):

```
struct Material {
    
    let id: String

    let materialName: String
    let brandName: String
    let alternativeNames: [String]?
    ...Many Other Constants...
}
```

Example of a material object as a global constant:

```
let myMaterial = Material(
        
    id: "myMaterial1",
    
    materialName: "myMaterial",
    brandName: "myMaterial 1",
    alternativeNames: ["myMaterial 1", "myFirstMaterial", "etc"],
```

Struct used to combine the material with other values:
struct MaterialList {

```
    let material: Material
    var isFavorite = false
}
```

Example of the global variable used of the combined structs:

```
var combinedMaterialList = [


MaterialList(material: myMaterial1, isFavorite: false),
MaterialList(material: myMaterial2, isFavorite: false),
...etc
]
```

**My question isn't how to use Core Data, but rather is this the way I should be setting up the data? Is using global constant/variables ok? Or should I be doing something else?**

Specifically, I was looking at SwiftUI a few weeks ago and in one of their tutorials, Apple made their model codable, and supplied the data with JSON. Before wrapping up a isFavorite variable inside of another model. Similar to the way I combined the structs.

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation#Get-to-Know-the-Sample-Data

Comment: The technique in that tutorial is one way to do it, but it's not one that works well with Core Data. With Core Data you need model objects that are instances of `NSManagedObject` or a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. You can still use `Codable` but you must use `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: Hey Tom, do you know of anywhere I can read more about this issue? I’m not exactly sure what to search for to find the information in looking for.

Comment: @TomHarrington Should I preload the data into Core Data?

Comment: Apple provides [documentation that should help explain about `NSManagedObject`s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata). Whether to preload the data depends on the app. If some data needs to already exist when someone first uses the app, preloading can be a good idea. Downloading it from a server the first time the app runs can also be good.

Comment: @TomHarrington Thank you! I'll look into it some more.